# PostgreSQL: how to delete duplicated rows grouped by the value of a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table, I need to delete every row corresponding to a certain "*id*" whenever all these rows are duplicated in a successive "*id*". Note that the deletion all rows for a specific "*id*" should happen only in case that **every** row between the two ids match (with the exception of the different "*id*" column).

| id | name | subject | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann | Maths | 9 |
| 1 | Ann | History | 8 |
| 2 | Ann | Maths | 9 |
| 2 | Ann | History | 8 |
| 3 | Ann | Maths | 9 |
| 3 | Ann | History | 7 |
| 4 | Bob | Maths | 8 |
| 4 | Bob | History | 8 |

For this specific input, the updated output table should be:

| id | name | subject | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann | Maths | 9 |
| 1 | Ann | History | 8 |
| 3 | Ann | Maths | 9 |
| 3 | Ann | History | 7 |
| 4 | Bob | Maths | 8 |
| 4 | Bob | History | 8 |

This because all records between id 1 and 2 are the exactly the same. This doesn't apply for "*id*" 1 and 3, as long as there's at least one row not in common between the two (id 1 has 8 in History while id 3 has 7 in the same subject).

So it is not as simple as deleting duplicated rows. Here's my attempt:

```
DELETE FROM  table a
USING table b
WHERE a.name = b.name
AND a.subject = b.subject
AND a.score = b.score
AND a.ID < b.ID;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get all ids that shouldn't be deleted and then exclude them in the `WHERE` clause of the `DELETE` statement.

**Step 1**. In order to match unique ids that are not repeated for all rows, you can use PostgreSQL [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) construct, that will allows you to get every row that is not duplicated on the fields "*name*", "*subject*", "*score*". Then retrieve these ids only once with a simple `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, subject, score) id
      FROM tab
      ORDER BY name, subject, score, id) ids_to_keep
```

**Step 2**. Hence you can build the `DELETE` statement using the `NOT IN` operator inside the `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, subject, score) id
          FROM tab
          ORDER BY name, subject, score, id) ids_to_keep
);
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5GWUCeEQ9jSBoY4gt5DGhm/0).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and help in editing the question for clarification!